# Pick minimum value and update all the rows SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a scenario  where I need to pick up a minimum value of a priority column and take the product of those and put it in all the columns.

```
SD  PL  PRIO    PRDT    PNAME
1   29  10      MM     CAR
1   LI  20      SS     BRAKE
1   AA  30      AA     ZZZZ
```

Since the Priority 10 is the minimum of gorup SD 1 MM should be replaced like below.

```
 SD PL  PRIO    PRDT    PNAME
 1  29  10      MM       CAR
 1  LI  20      MM       BRAKE
 1  AA  30      MM       ZZZZ
```

Could you please help with the select query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
SELECT
    t.SD, t.PL, t.PRIO, t2.PRDT, t.PNAME
FROM YourTable t
INNER JOIN(
    SELECT *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY SD ORDER BY PRIO) AS rn
    FROM YourTable
) t2
    ON t.SD = t2.SD
WHERE t2.rn = 1
```

---

How about using a correlated subquery:

```
UPDATE YourTable t
    SET PRDT = (
        SELECT PRDT
        FROM YourTable t2
        WHERE 
            t2.SD = t.SD
            AND t2.PRIO = (SELECT MIN(t3.PRIO) FROM YourTable t3 WHERE t3.SD = t.SD)
    )
```

Comment: I do not want to update the table. Select query would help.

Comment: @Mani Updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this if you want only SELECT Query.

```
SELECT COL1,
  COL2,
  MIN(COL3) OVER(PARTITION BY COL1 ORDER BY COL3 ASC) COL3,
  COL4,
  COL5
FROM
  (SELECT 1 COL1, '29' COL2, 10 COL3, 'MM' COL4, 'CAR' COL5 FROM DUAL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 1 COL1, 'LI' COL2, 20 COL3, 'SS' COL4, 'BRAKE' COL5 FROM DUAL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 1 COL1, 'AA' COL2, 30 COL3, 'AA' COL4 , 'ZZZZ' COL5 FROM DUAL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 2 COL1, '29' COL2, 10 COL3, 'MM' COL4, 'CAR' COL5 FROM DUAL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 2 COL1, 'LI' COL2, 05 COL3, 'SS' COL4, 'BRAKE' COL5 FROM DUAL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 2 COL1, 'AA' COL2, 30 COL3, 'AA' COL4 , 'ZZZZ' COL5 FROM DUAL
  );
```

Comment: It is not the minimum of COL3 . Pick the minimum of COL3 equivalent COL4 and replace in COL4.